# ethereumjs-tx Returned error: invalid sender

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

When i am trying to send signed transaction via ethereumjs-tx. I get this `Returned error: invalid sender`

```
web3Http.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress,"pending").then(function(blockcount){
   
    result = web3Http.utils.toWei(amt.toString(), 'ether');
   
   
          count = blockcount;
    
         
          var rawTransaction = {
           "from":myAddress,
           "gasPrice":web3Http.utils.toHex(20* 1e9),
           "gasLimit":web3Http.utils.toHex(210000),
           "to":contractAddress,"value":"0x0",
           "data":contract.methods.approve(fromAddress,web3Http.utils.toHex(result)).encodeABI(),
           "nonce":web3Http.utils.toHex(count)
          }
         
          var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction,{'chain':'rinkeby',hardfork: 'petersburg'});
          
          transaction.sign(Buffer.from(process.env.Key, 'hex'));
      
          web3Http.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x'+transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
          .on('receipt', ((data)=>{
            resolve(data);
           
          }))
```

Comment: 1. Make sure that `process.env.Key` doesn't start with `0x`.

Comment: 2. The `'0x'+` part seems redundant (and harmful).

Comment: Nope ```process.env.Key``` doesn't start with ```0x ```  and removing ```0x+``` part doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Change the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var transaction_data = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3Http.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3Http.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey = Buffer.from('abcde', 'hex')

        var transaction = new Tx(transaction_data,{ chain: 'ropsten' , hardfork: 'petersburg' });

        transaction.sign(privateKey);

        web3Http.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + transaction.serialize().toString('hex'))
            .on('transactionHash', console.log);
```

to the below

```
      const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;

      var transaction_data = {
        "from": myAddress,
        "gasPrice": web3Http.utils.toHex(20 * 1e9),
        "gasLimit": web3Http.utils.toHex(210000),
        "to": contractAddress,
        "value": "0x0",
        "data": contract.methods.safeTransferFrom(myAddress, toAddress, tokenId).encodeABI(),
      }

        var privateKey ='abcde'

        web3Http.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transaction_data, privateKey)
        .then(function(value){
            web3Http.eth.sendSignedTransaction(value.transaction_data)
            .then(function(response){
              console.log("response:" + JSON.stringify(response, null, ' '));
            })
          })
```

`web3Http.eth.accounts.signTransaction` will take the burden of including the correct chainId and nonce .
Reference: https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/1040